# Hubot-hipchat works 1-1 chat but not on a room

Tags: node.js, heroku, hubot

Whenever I throw a command at hubot in a room i.e `@hubot help` I get nothing, but typing `help` in 1-1 chat works fine, am I missing something? has anyone else had this problem??

i have followed the setup instructions to the tee, and it still wont work

Answer (score 3):

Did you end up specifying a host? I was having a similar problem, and removing the hostname fixed it. See the GH issue here:

https://github.com/github/hubot/issues/651

In my case, **I could see in the logs that Hubot was receiving the commands, and even replying with the correct response**, but the response was never showing up in the channel:

In the chat room (no visible in-room response):

`@hubot ping`

```
[Mon Feb 24 2014 02:04:21 GMT+0000 (UTC)] DEBUG Message '[object Object]' matched regex //^[@]?hubot[:,]?\s*(?:PING$)/i/
[Mon Feb 24 2014 02:04:21 GMT+0000 (UTC)] DEBUG OUT > 
<message to="XXXXXX_hubot_test@conf.hipchat.com" type="chat" from="XXXXXX_XXXXXX@chat.hipchat.com/hubot-hipchat">
<inactive xmlns="http://jabber/protocol/chatstates"/>
<body>PONG</body>
</message>
```

In 1:1 messages:

```
[Mon Feb 24 2014 02:06:01 GMT+0000 (UTC)] DEBUG Message '[object Object]' matched regex //^[@]?hubot[:,]?\s*(?:PING$)/i/
[Mon Feb 24 2014 02:06:01 GMT+0000 (UTC)] DEBUG OUT > 
<message to="XXXXX_188883@chat.hipchat.com" type="chat" from="XXXXXXXX@chat.hipchat.com/hubot-hipchat">
<inactive xmlns="http://jabber/protocol/chatstates"/>
<body>PONG</body>
</message>
```

I think the issue is that it uses chat.hipchat.com for 1:1 chat, and conf.hipchat.com for rooms. If you specified a specific hostname, you'll get one or the other, but not both.

If you set the environmental variables via CLI, to unset it, do

`unset HUBOT_HIPCHAT_HOST`.

Comment: I had the same problem as OP: I commented out HUBOT_HIPCHAT_XMPP_DOMAIN (which had the conf path though) from the config and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Have you only tried: `@hubot help`? You can set up your prefix via: [Here](https://github.com/github/hubot/blob/master/docs/patterns.md) It does say that the

> For example, the HipChat Adapter converts @hubot into hubot: before passing it to Hubot.

But I'd go ahead and try the following. Also attempt to try it locally via `bin/hubot` running it via the shell.

1. Hubot help
2. hubot help

Not to mention check `heroku logs` to make sure that hubot is showing up in your hipchat channel correctly.

Hope this helps.